# STM32L476RG ADC bare metal

Tags: stm32, c, keil, nucleo

I bought STM32L476RG nucleo to learn bare metal programming. Im following a online course on udemy and so far i have suceeded with everything except hitting a wall now with ADC. First of all i have read through reference manual countless times and tried to follow everything thats said in there. Based on that i wrote my code. However i don't know did i get all the registers correctly set up or i missed something. Im trying to measure ADC_IN6 value which is connected to PA1 and send the value over UART. All tutorials are with HAL, but im not using HAL. Im using Keil Uvision for programming. And i can't debug my either since Keil doesn't recognize my nucleo for some reason. I got this ADC working with STM32CUBEID using HAL, but this didn't help much either. I tried to find differences but HAL is so overwhelming. At least my potentiometer connections should be fine. I read from reference manual that i need to calibrate my ADC every time it wakes up from deep sleep. I took calibration out for now till i get something. Im mostly concerned about my SQR register value, is it correct for ADC1_IN6?

The other problem i have is basic C question. How can i send ADC value which is number between 0-4095 over UART? Is printf really my only option? I can send this value over UART in STM32CUBEID when i use HAL with stdio library. However i would like to do same in keil. Printf haven't really worked out well either. How to implement it with my line which sends bits directly from USART2->TDR register.

Thanks in advance. If you have any questions regarding to my code let me know. Systick and UART_init part are working fine. I have added comments to each line which should explain what each line is doing.

```
#include "stm32l4xx.h"                  // Device header

void systickDelayMs(int n);
void USART2_Init(void);

//PA1 connected to ADC12_IN6(ADC1 and ADC2 share same input)
//tADCVREG_STUP(ADC voltage regulator start-up time = 20µs)

uint16_t analogValue;

int main(void)
{
    
    
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1;       //Port A clock enable
    GPIOA->MODER = 0x00000000; //Initialize GPIOA MODER register to all 0(by default all F)
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0xC;     //Set PA1 to analog state
    GPIOA->ASCR |= 0x2;      //Connect analog switch to the ADC input(PORT A input 1), only necessary on STM32L47x/L48x devices
    
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= 0x2000;  //ADC clock enable
    ADC1->CR = 0x00000000;   //Disable deep-power-down by setting DEEPPWD to 0
    ADC1->CR |= 0x2;         //ADDIS(ADC disable command); disable the ADC
    ADC1->SQR1 = 0x180;      //First conversion is ADC1_IN6 because PA1 is connected to ADC1_IN6
    ADC1->CR |= 0x10000000;  //Enable ADC voltage regulator by setting ADVREGEN to 1
    systickDelayMs(1);       //Wait 1 ms to start-up ADC voltage regulator
    
    //ADC calibration(make sure ADCALDIF is in correct state, write 1 when needed calibration in differential inputs mode)
    //ADC1->CR |= 0x80000000;  //Start ADC calibration by setting ADCAL to 1
    //systickDelayMs(100);     //Wait 100   ms to be sure ADC calibration is finished
    
    //Enable ADC
    ADC1->ISR |= 1;          //Clear ADC ready by setting ADRDY to 1
    ADC1->CR |= 1;           //Enable ADC by setting ADEN to 1
    systickDelayMs(10);     //Wait 10   ms to let ADC stabilize
    
    USART2_Init();
    
    while(1)
    {
        ADC1->CR |= 0x4;                  //Start ADC conversion
        while(!(ADC1->ISR & 0x4)){}       //Wait for ADC conversion to be complete
        analogValue = ADC1->DR;
        while(!(USART2->ISR & 0x0080)){}  //Wait for Tx buffer empty
        USART2->TDR = analogValue; //need help with this line as well
        systickDelayMs(500);
    }
}


void USART2_Init(void)
{
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1;
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= 0x20000;
    
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x7700; //Configure PA2 as USART2 TX and configure PA3 as USART2 RX
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x00A0; //Enable alternate function for PA2, PA3
    
    USART2->BRR = 0x1A1; //9600 baud @4Mhz
    USART2->CR1 = 0x000C; //Enable Tx, Rx
    USART2->CR1 |= 1; //Enable USART2
    
}

void systickDelayMs(int n)
{
    SysTick->LOAD = 4000; //Reload with number of clocks per millisecond
    SysTick->VAL = 0;     //Clear current value register
    SysTick->CTRL = 0x5;  //Enable Systick
    
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //Wait until the COUNT flag is set
        while((SysTick->CTRL & 0x10000) ==0){}
    }
    SysTick->CTRL =0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot regarding my answer to user Lundin.]

Edit: Added screenshot regarding my answer to user Lundin.

Comment: The problem is nobody will bother to check those bits agains the datasheet. Using magic numbers makes it hard for you and everyone to know if that is right or wrong. Since you use the ST headers for register access, why not use the register bit names it provides too? And if Keil does not work for you, use CubeIDE then if debugging works. Why not start with working HAL program and then rewrite your custom drivers one by one so in the end you don't need HAL? And typically numbers are converted into decimal ASCII characters to print them, there are several methods, but C also gives sprintf.

Comment: I was afraid so. Was hoping maybe someone has at least some kind of reference code. What you mean by ST register bit names? Just one example? Even if you can't help me with ADC maybe someone takes few minutes to answer C problem. Im gonna ask one more specific question. Is my SQR1 register correct?

Comment: It's better not to ask unrelated questions in a single post. Please edit your question accordingly. Also, as @Justme said, it will be easier to start with *STM32CubeIDE*, which is free and easy to install & use. You don't need to use HAL, you can create empty projects with it. Once you have enough experience, you can migrate to other IDEs if you wish.

Comment: You really ought to get your in-circuit debugger working or you'd be stumbling around in the dark. If you paid for Keil then poke their support.

Comment: OK so I haven't used this part but an internal voltage regulator isn't common in ADC peripherals. It seems you have decided to use that one on purpose, yes? Or do you have any external Vref supply on ADC pins? Also, what does the hardware manual say about this voltage regulator, do you need to use external caps and if so are they there?

Comment: Regarding getting rid of all your "magic numbers", check out [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290), particularly the part about bit masks in the end.

Comment: My ADC vref+ is connected with VDD. No external voltage reference. Its nucleo board designed by ST. Also my ADC_IN6 works with HAL. But i can't debug. I can't debug in Keil and also i have problems debugging in STM32CUBEID. Im using free version of Keil.  The reason why i enable ADVREGEN is written in reference manual. It says to do that. I will add a picture.

Comment: If you use a smart editor that supports tags, you can walk through the HAL function line by line. Search engine term: "ctags". Then maybe you will see if you omitted something. It is a tedious process. But it is not overly complex. Once the ADC is configured PROPERLY all you have to do is start a conversion, poll until it is complete, then read the result.